# How to show full compile error messages info in Checker FrameWork with line numbers etc

Tags: checker-framework

I just started using Checker Framework and have a problem that is exactly reproducible on one of the example projects from authors of this framework. This project is available here:
https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/tree/master/docs/examples/GradleExamples

When i run this command from root:

```
>gradle compileJava
```

i receive this compilation output:

```
       public static /*@Nullable*/ Object nullable = null;
                                                  ^

  required: @Initialized @NonNull Object

        list.add(null); // error on this line
                 ^

  required: @Initialized @NonNull String
2 errors
:compileJava FAILED
```

As you can see there is no any information about where errors occur like class name, line number in code etc.
I did not find any information in their official manual about any compiler parameters that can change output format appropriately. I want error messages look like this:

```
~\GradleExample.java:33 error: ';' expected
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I achieve this behaviour on 3 machines:

1. - OS: Microsoft Windows 7 x64 Ultimate SP1 [version 6.1.7601];
   - Java: 1.8.0_73;
   - Gradle: 2.14.
2. - OS: Microsoft Windows 10 x64 Pro [version 10.0.14393];
   - Java: 1.8.0_121;
   - Gradle: 3.4.1.
3. - OS: Microsoft Windows 7 x64 Ultimate SP1 [version 6.1.7601];
   - Java: 1.8.0_121;
   - Gradle: 3.4.1.

The absence of line numbers and class names is experienced only when running with Gradle. I also tried to run checker with Maven and with Javac from command line and it worked perfectly.
To configure Checker Framework with Gradle i followed steps from manual. There are 3 steps:

1. Download framework;
2. Unzip it to create a checker-framework directory;
3. Configure Gradle to include Checker Framework on the classpath.

As i understand, Gradle will do steps 1 and 2 automatically when providing needed Checker Framework's jars through dependency management. Nevertheless i tried both options:

1. dependency management:
   I simply downloaded example project and executed "gradle compileJava" from root 
   of the GradleJava7Example project.
2. manually writing paths in gradle build file:

```java
    allprojects {

        tasks.withType(JavaCompile).all { JavaCompile compile ->

            compile.options.compilerArgs = [
            '-processor', 'org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker',
            '-processorpath', "C:\\checker-framework-2.1.10\\checker\\dist\\checker.jar",
            "-Xbootclasspath/p:C:\\checker-framework-2.1.10\\checker\\dist\\jdk8.jar",
            '-classpath', 'C:\\checker-framework-2.1.10\\checker\\dist\\checker.jar;C:\\checker-framework-2.1.10\\checker\\dist\\javac.jar'
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  When I tried the example, the output included line numbers.  Can you provide more details?  What OS, what version of Java, what version of gradle, are you using the GradleJava7Example or the GradleJava8Example, are you using the Checker Framework distribution or did you clone it from GitHub, etc.?  Please give a complete recipe to reproduce the problem, preferably starting with installing the Checker Framework.  Then others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround. I'll explain it later, but now if somebody has the same problem, add this line to you JavaCompile tasks configuration:

```java
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile).all { JavaCompile compile ->

        System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n")  // <<<<<< add this line

        compile.options.compilerArgs = [
            '-processor', 'org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker',
            '-processorpath', "${configurations.checkerFramework.asPath}",
            "-Xbootclasspath/p:${configurations.checkerFrameworkAnnotatedJDK.asPath}"
        ]
    }
}
```

First of all i must say that problem was not in Checker Framework at all. I managed to reproduce the same behavior as mentioned in question without Checker Framework. I have created a little custom Annotation Processor. Here is the code:

```java
@SupportedSourceVersion(value = SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes(value = {"*"})
public class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor{

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        String sepr = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "[error code] " + sepr + " catched!!!");

        return true;
    }

}
```

As you can see, all it does is printing a message right away from start. Note that i used a line separator provided by  `java.lang.System` class to split message. When i registered this processor and tried to run "gradle compileJava" from gradle project it produced the following output:

```
:compileJava

    catched!!!

1 error
:compileJava FAILED
```

The property "line.separator" for Windows OS returns CR+LF: "\r\n". I don't know why `Messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind kind, CharSequence msg)` has this behaviour, because when i type `System.err.print("[error code] " + sepr + " catched!!!")` instead, everything works fine (note also that this problem occur only when i use Gradle, if i run manually javac with all arguments or use Maven everyting is fine).
I found that if i substitude the provided by system separator with simple "\n" symbol compiler error messages are displayed correctly.
For now i choose this solution as a workaround.